# kernel communication between VM(guest) and host

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to send message from VM kernel to host kernel without net like socket. I refer to `hypercall` but still can not know how to use. Is there any tutorials or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility might be to use `AF_NETLINK` sockets documented in [netlink(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html). You might need to code then load your own Linux [kernel module](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/kernel_modules.html).